# How to apply a reduce OpenACC directive to a multidimensional vector?

Tags: c++, openacc

I'm trying to paralelize some code with OpenACC.

```
        #pragma acc parallel loop reduction (+:matriz())
        for(auto i = 0; i <= (width-siz); i += siz)
            for(auto j = 0; j <= (width-siz); j += siz)
                for(auto k = 0; k <= (width-siz); k += siz)
                    for(auto l = 0; l <= (width-siz); l += siz)
                        matriz[i][j][k][l] = matriz[i][j][k+1][l] + matriz[i][j][k][l+1];
```

matriz is declared like this:

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<short>>>> matriz;
```

I compile with this command:

```
pgc++ -std=c++11 -acc -ta=multicore,tesla -Minfo=accel  boxcount4d.cpp -o boxcount4d
```

And I get this error:

```
"boxcount4d.cpp", line 304: error: expected a ")"
          #pragma acc parallel loop reduction (+:matriz())
                                                       ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "boxcount4d.cpp".
```

I don't know if it is just a syntax error or if I have to use this library https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html because I couln't use STL vectors with OpenACC

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error due to the extra "()".  Correct syntax would be:

```
#pragma acc parallel loop reduction (+:matriz)
```

Though why are you using a reduction here?  It's not needed since you're not trying parallelize the k and l loops.

> I couln't use STL vectors with OpenACC

You can use vectors in device code, though vectors are not thread safe so you need to be careful to only use the access operator, "[]".  Also it's recommended to compile with CUDA unified memory ("-ta=multicore,tesla:managed") since manually trying to copy vectors can be difficult.